# Adding Page Numbers to Table of Contents in RDLC Report

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reporting, rdlc

I am Working on RDLC reports, I draw two tables.

1. First table is for table of contents
2. Second table is used to show the detail of each section

both controls have the save data set.
i also applied page number in footer also

I want to show the page number in table of contents also, How can I do that? Need Help?

I tried to calculate the page number or find page number but unable to do that,

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: First i try to place a variable and try to update it value in the footer and then use that value for table of content, but it gives me exception..
Second i try to use bookmarks on the name of first table so that when user click on it, redirect to that part, again its not working in pdf file, but when i export that file in word, and hover on that table cell it show me the name of section and ask to press ctrl + ut nothing happens..